# Geolocation App Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, geolocation, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, geospatial

I've no experience with geo location based apps and want to build a geolaction based app with a backend written in nodejs and running on google cloud.

My main problem is how to design the database and which db should I use (Bigtable or Datastore)? The main query is to query places at a given location and radius. I have read a lot about the geohash, but the nodejs librarys aren't so good now.

So what are you recommend me for chosing and designing database?

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to store the data in relational format, perform frequent
  joins between location/co-ordinates and the amount of data being
  processed is less (>50 GB), then go for [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/).
- [Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview) is ideal for storing very large amounts of
  single-keyed data with very low latency. It has great integration
  services with most of the Apache projects.
- If there is no requirement of data to be in the relational format,
  and frequent insertions and updations are required on huge amounts of
  data, go for [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview). The querying process would be
  slightly different and difficult for a naive person to understand.
- You can also use [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) which processes TBs of data within a
  few seconds, if frequent insertions and updations are not required.
  It is more of a data store.

Have a look at the following URL for better insights: https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/

Google has also announced [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/) which is a relational
 database service that offers great consistency and speed (still be
 beta). It is still in early stage, but can revolutionise the concepts
 of SQL vs NoSQL.

All of the above databases have querying libraries written for NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

[GeoMesa](http://www.geomesa.org/), an Apache licensed open source suite of tools that enables large-scale geospatial analytics, [works with Cloud Bigtable](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/current/user/bigtable/install.html).  I don't know how well this will interact with node.js, but it's worth considering a framework like GeoMesa since it will likely enable you to focus more on your core product.